# AjaxForm clear file input element

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, input

I have a html form that I have turned into an ajaxForm via the ajaxForm({...}) call.  One of the elements is a fileInputElement.  Also, I have integrated a MultiSelector ([MultiSelector Source](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-file-element/)).  When the input element changes I do some validation to make sure the user selected a file that matches something they marked on the web page.  The issue I have is, if the user selects a bad file, I return false, but then the file input element is still pointing at the 'bad' file that the user selected.  I would either like to prevent this or clear it after returning false.  Any ideas?

For reference, simply changing the value of a file input element is not allowed for security reasons.  I tried the 'innerHTML' trick of setting innerHTML to itself, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick JS solution - just replace it, with a new one (not ideal, but should work):

Something along those lines:

HTML:

```
<div id="some_file_field_wrapper">
    <input type="file" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var file_html = '<input type="file" />';
var elem_id   = 'some_file_field_wrapper';
document.getElementById( elem_id ).innerHTML = file_html;
```

Comment: I realized this after I posted that this was probably the best way to go.  This is the solution I more or less ended up using.  Due to using Multifile, I ended up basically adding a new file input before the one to be deleted, then removed the one to be deleted from the parentNode.

Answer (score 2):

here is a post explaining how to do the same using jquery.. : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/clear-upload-file-input-field-jquery/

hope this helps...

Comment: I did try resetting the form, but that clears everything.  I found another solution as marked below, but this may still be a valid option.